# In NOVA version 4, How to override the detail (single) view of a resource

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-nova

In NOVA version 4, I have created a resource name "Orders". I want a custom design for single (detail) view of Order. Please anybody, help me how to override the default Detail.Vue.

[image]

As shown in screenshot, i want to customize this page